# How can I stamp text on generated PDF pages?

Tags: pdf-generation, itext

From your help I have managed to get a  very nice PDF generation tool built.  It builds a PDF based off of a 5 page template.  On the 3rd and 5th page there is a possibility of needing additional pages added and moving the next pages down.  The 5th page is landscape even.  Everything works perfect except one little additional functionality that I am looking for.

The template that I have built has form fields on the fifth page.  Therefore, I use the following code to fill the field:

```
var pdfReader = new PdfReader(existingFileStream);
var stamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, newFileStream);
var form = stamper.AcroFields;

form.SetField("fkClientName", clientName);
```

The field gets filled just fine, but not on the additional pages.  Which is weird because I do call this line:

```
PdfImportedPage templatePage = stamper.GetImportedPage(pdfReader, 5);
```

I feel like it should see that there is form fields on that fifth page.  However, I read that stamper.GetImportedPage does not retrieve form fields.  I don't really care if it's a form field or text.  I just need the client name at the top of each generated additional page.  Here is what my columntext code looks like that builds the additional pages:

```
while (true)
      {
       ct.SetSimpleColumn(-75, 75, PageSize.A4.Height + 25, PageSize.A4.Width - 200);
       if (!ColumnText.HasMoreText(ct.Go()))
             break;
       pageNum++;
       stamper.InsertPage(pageNum, new Rectangle(792f, 612f));
       stamper.GetOverContent(pageNum).AddTemplate(templatePage, 0, -1f, 1f, 0, 0, PageSize.A4.Width);
       ct.Canvas = stamper.GetOverContent(pageNum);
      }
```

Comment: You are ignoring the fact that page content is stored in content streams (which are copied when using `GetImportedPage`), whereas widget annotations are stored in annotation dictionaries (which aren't part of the content stream). The behavior you're describing is perfectly normal, but I can't post this comment as an answer, because I don't understand the question: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I see, that makes sense.  Let me see if I can explain what I am trying to do then.

Basically, when ct.go runs, it'll generate new pages if we exceed the size of the columntext.  When we hit a new page.  I just want to insert text at the top of the new pages, outside of the columntext box.  It'll be stored in a string(it's just the client's name.)  Is it possible to do this?

Comment: This might be a better way to explain it.  My columntext holds a table of data.  If this table is too big for the page, it generates a new page.  On that new page, I just want to add a title to the top of it from a string.

Answer (score 0):

If you had company stationery with some kind of background and you wanted to create a document that has flowing text (a column that can flow over to the next page) that also has a repeating header, then I would prefer using `PdfWriter`.

I'd use `PdfWriter` to add the content (without using `ColumnText`, just use the page size and the margins to define the column) and I would add the background and the header using page events. See for instance the [Stationery](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=114) example from my book.

I'd create a subclass for `PdfPageEventHelper` and I'd load the page you want to see repeated into a `PdfImportedPage` instance named `page`:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(STATIONERY);
page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, 1);
```

You may also want to initialize a `Phrase` with the name of your customer:

```
header = new Phrase(customerName);
```

Then you override the `onEndPage()` method like this:

```
public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
    writer.getDirectContentUnder().addTemplate(page, 0, 0);
    ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContent(),
        Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, header, 36, 806, 0);
}
```

Now you don't have to worry about `ColumnText` and new pages. Every time a new page is created, the background and the header will be added automatically.

However, you are using `PdfStamper` because your original document isn't company stationery: it's a 5 page document. If this document doesn't contain any interactive elements (you've created it using iTextSharp, so you know if it's a *flat* document or not), I'd still try the `PdfWriter` approach and change the `page` instance in the event whenever a new page is needed.

If you want to keep on using `PdfStamper`, you'll have to add the header in a different way. For instance using a different `ColumnText` instance, or, if it's a single line, using `ColumnText.showTextAligned()`. If you don't know the coordinates for the header, you can retrieve the position of the field using the `getFieldPositions()` method.

Comment: Is it possible to use     PDFWriter while using      PdfStamper ?  I would hate to rewrite everything I have already done just to insert the client's name.  Or do I need to close the stamper before being able to access the document?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Also: "I would hate to rewrite everything" sounds strange when talking about only a handful of lines. I'm currently on the move (been flying for 12 hours and the airline "misplaced" all my luggage). I won't be able to visit SO in the next couple of days.

Comment: No problem, I appreciate your help with my last few troubles.  I honestly am a bit limited on time as well.  I am going to give it a good effort this weekend.  If I still have trouble, I will reply here.  Thanks again and have a safe trip.

Comment: @Leyth G Have you found a solution to your problem? I am stuck on the same thing now...